# Automatically adding polygons at door openings using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, polygon-creation

I'm seeking a way to add windows and doors automatically to thier places using ArcGIS Pro, the door or the window is represented as a simple 4 sided polygon, and the added polygons should be on a separate layer than the walls.
The openings are already in their locations I'm looking for a way to fill them with polygons with the same dimension as the opening automatically and not one by one.
In the example below the pink polygons represent the final outcome I need after exporting GIS file to AutoCAD (the above also applies to the rooms openings which are not done yet in the example).

[image]

Comment: can you be specific in GIS software - looks like AutoCAD from the screenshot.

Comment: There are shortcuts to templates to do this in AutoCAD - see the wrong way and then the correct way in this video short https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3h87DXSprU

Comment: I don't want to add them manually one by one in AutoCAD, I will edit the question to be more specific